# Delayed Linux kernel panic when change the PFN in a PTE

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I am running a kernel module, and i hit a kernel panic after a while when the module is unloaded.
The kernel module does several things.
1. virt_addr1 = kmalloc(4096);
2. virt_addr2 = kmalloc(4096);
3. find the PTEs for virt_addr1 and virt_addr2.
4. set the PFN of virt_addr1 to the PTE of virt_addr2, so virt_addr2 and virt_addr1 basically point to the same PFN and the page.
5. flushing the TLB by calling invlpg.
6. change back PTE of virt_addr2 to its original PFN.
7. kfree(virt_adddr1) and kfree(virt_addr2);
8. unload the module.

run 'make' in module dir, then kernel panic as follows,

```
[ 1980.579451] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff811ff44a>]  [<ffffffff811ff44a>] getname_kernel+0xda/0x120
[ 1980.583728] RSP: 0018:ffff8804a596bd38  EFLAGS: 00010283
[ 1980.586396] RAX: 1111111111111111 RBX: 1111111111111111 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1980.590111] RDX: 000000000001bd58 RSI: 1111111111111111 RDI: 111111111111112d
[ 1980.593795] RBP: ffff8804a596bd58 R08: ffff8804a0dfbc00 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1980.597418] R10: 2d3638782d78756e R11: 00322e6f732e3436 R12: 000000000000001c
[ 1980.601093] R13: fffffffffffffff4 R14: ffff8804a1380f20 R15: ffff8804a1bee038
[ 1980.604736] FS:  00007efd1517c700(0000) GS:ffff8804bd940000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1980.608942] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1980.611885] CR2: 00007fb42fc7ad0c CR3: 00000004a5864000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
[ 1980.615509] Stack:
[ 1980.616565]  ffff8800ba1fb380 ffff8804a0dfae00 00000000fffffff8 ffff8804a596c000
[ 1980.620540]  ffff8804a596bd78 ffffffff811f5b91 ffff8800ba1fb380 ffff8804a0dfae00
[ 1980.624527]  ffff8804a596be60 ffffffff81249e4c 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[ 1980.628518] Call Trace:
[ 1980.629791]  [<ffffffff811f5b91>] open_exec+0x11/0x50
[ 1980.632362]  [<ffffffff81249e4c>] load_elf_binary+0x2bc/0x1710
[ 1980.635288]  [<ffffffff811a0222>] ? get_user_pages+0x52/0x60
[ 1980.638132]  [<ffffffff811f610e>] search_binary_handler+0x9e/0x1d0
[ 1980.641241]  [<ffffffff811f79dc>] do_execveat_common.isra.36+0x52c/0x710
[ 1980.645204]  [<ffffffff811f7e5a>] SyS_execve+0x3a/0x50
[ 1980.648518]  [<ffffffff81804ba5>] stub_execve+0x5/0x5
[ 1980.651829]  [<ffffffff8180491b>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x6a
[ 1980.655781] Code: 80 80 06 00 00 48 85 c0 74 0e 8b 00 85 c0 75 08 48 89 df e8 69 e7 f0 ff 49 89 dd 5b 4c 89 e8 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 48 8d 78 1c <48> 89 38 eb a3 48 8b 3d ca 34 d3 00 48 89 c6 49 c7 c5 dc ff ff
```

Comment: Are `virt_addr1` and `virt_addr2` page aligned  (perhaps this is a dumb question)? Does using `__get_free_page()` and `free_page()` make any difference?

Comment: Good point. I used kmalloc, and the virt_addr1 and virt_addr2 are both page aligned.   I tried to use use page's API, and I got the same error.   I don't know if there is anything in the PTE/page struct, which is referred by other kernel components, which may trigger the crash after changing the PTE fields.

Answer (score 0):

With lots of tests and reboots, I think I got the way to fix the panic.
Between
6. change back PTE of virt_addr2 to its original PFN.
7. kfree(virt_adddr1) and kfree(virt_addr2);
It needs to flush the TLB again after change the PTE back to its original PFN.

With this TLB flushing, there is NO PANIC again.
I don't know the reason behind, if anyone can share more details, that will be great.